# jQuery disables submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The following jQuery-code has been designed to change the style of an input in case a user submits a form without filling the field beforehand. Alongside changing the style of the input, it blocks the submit-event whenever the field is empty. However, it also blocks the event whenever something is in it. Does anybody know why?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#form1, #form2').submit(function(event) {
        if($.trim($(this).children('input').val()).length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form class="center" id="form1" action="/success" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Content..." class="form-control input-lg">
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KVWg2/. Where's #form2?

Comment: Fixed it, children() was the issue. I had an additional div-tag included and children() just selects the direct tags following the parent-tag. Thanks for your assistance nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function () 
    {
        $('#form1').submit
        (
            function (e) 
            {
                if ($('[name="content"]').val() == '') // You can add an id and select by id
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('[name="content"]').attr('class', 'has-error');
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Form2 and try:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
        if($.trim($(this).children('input').val()).length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```